# Deleting records from a DE 3 months after they are added

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation, automationstudio, sql

I want to write an automation which deletes records from a certain DE after the present date is 3 months after their date_added attribute. I know this is possible with DELETE FROM and DATEADD() in SQL, but I can only write SELECT statements in the SQL Query option within Automation Studio. How do I build this automation now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the deletion based on rolling 3 months period within individual record level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an automation, I would rather utilise the [Data Retention](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213832&type=1) policy for that particular DE. This feature can remove individual records after a specified number of days, without any SQL activities.

This of course under the assumption of, that your date_added corresponds to the timestamp of the entry being created in the said DE

Comment: I solved it by using the Data Retention policy on the data extension. Thanks!